# Cardholder to Merchant SET Protocol

Tags: encryption, public-key

I have some doubts regarding the SET protocol. Let say the Alice payment information runs through a sha-1 hash function which is a one-way algorithm, irreversible to create a message digest. How do bob verify that the message is really from alice since he can't see the content of the message which bob shouldn't see in the first place?

Based on my understanding, it has something to do with public digital signature and comparing it with the message digest but I don't get it. Can anyone explain the concept to me in layman terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SET, Bob the merchant doesnt need to know message is from Alice the cardholder. Bob needs to get paid for the order received. So Bob proceeds on response from Acquirer (running a SET payment gateway) telling him this particular cardholder (whatever the name) has sufficient funds in his account. This would likely mean funds were reserved, according to policy of issuing bank.

Yes, a "dual signature" was introduced in SET, meaning message to be signed is actually just two hashes, one is the order and the other is payment information. Merchant is supposed to receive the order and the hash of payment information, unless gateway would open more details.

Comment: Ok I am still somewhat confused. I'm just don't really understand how the comparing of message digest works. Alice sent the message digest (55fse5fsef45esfs5f45es) hash of payment information to bob, bob can't see it (He not suppose to). Bob send it to payment gateway, how the payment gateway decrypt the hash  (55fse5fsef45esfs5f45es)?

Comment: I think i get it. It is the comparing of TWO HASH value. No one will know the real content of the payment information which contain the cardholder credit card number or ccv. But here's my next question, in that case, how do the gateway generate a hash value to compare? why can't the merchant generate a hash value too if he wants to?

Comment: Apart from two hashes, Alice the cardholder also sends payment information encrypted with public key of payment gateway, so gateway will know it.